# .Net Async WebService call

Tags: .net, web-services

I know all about threading applications, but haven't done this over web services before. Rather than have the client manage various threads, I want to just fire an async method and get the result from a callback.

It looks straight forward enough - just call the async method in the proxy class generated by visual studio. BUT WAIT... there isn't anywhere for me to specify a call back.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480512.aspx) and other [sites](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/async_xmlws.aspx) tell me I should be using  Begin[MethodName] and End[MethodName], but they don't appear to exist/been-generated, I do have the [MethodName]Async method which is good ([see here](http://www.developer.com/net/vb/article.php/1443981/Asynchronous-Web-Services-for-Visual-Basic-NET.htm)), but it doesn't have an option to pass in a delegate/callback.

I also have (staticly) ServiceName.MethodNameEventHandler/Args available, but can't use it as it isn't part of the instantiated service.

What is going on? and how can I send/receive a call back from a web service. I have noticed all the googling I've done provides me with pretty old sites. Can anyone provide me with an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have [MethodName]Async methods, you should have [MethodName]Completed events, which you can subscribe to, and that will act as your callback.

In vb.net it should be something like this:

```
AddHandler yourWebProxyClassInstance.[MethodName]Completed, AddressOf YourMethod
```

Comment: How can I do this in vb.net? do you have any pages? I do have access to these methods, but only the async method is an instance method.

Comment: ...    AddHandler _svc.UploadPartCompleted, AddressOf x(object evnt)?

Comment: yes, similar. You'll need to adjust the method signature to match that of the Completed event.

Comment: Yup, done that - bit rusty on the vb.net syntax is slightly different to C#.

Answer (score 0):

I believe when you generate the web services through VS that there is a checkbox if you want to create async methods.  Maybe you forgot to check that and so your services don't have the begin and end methods?

Comment: Doesn't appear to exists - where on the add web references is this supposed to be - look at the last screen shot on this web page http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2008/03/18/where-the-heck-is-add-web-reference-in-visual-studio-2008.aspx

Comment: IIRC, this is only on the Add Service Reference in VS2008+. You can, however, use Add Service Reference to a .asmx web-service.